# How to put an array object in hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to solve this but I'm stuck here for a while now. My problem is I can't find a way on how to put an array object to my hashmap.

Here's my example code of hashmap for dropdown menu that I got from google.

```
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> data2 = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
private String country; 
private String city;  
private Map<String, String> countries;
private Map<String,String> cities;

 countries  = new HashMap<String, String>();
        countries.put("USA", "USA");
        countries.put("Germany", "Germany");
        countries.put("Brazil", "Brazil");

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("New York", "New York");
        map.put("San Francisco", "San Francisco");
        map.put("Denver", "Denver");
        data2.put("USA", map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Berlin", "Berlin");
        map.put("Munich", "Munich");
        map.put("Frankfurt", "Frankfurt");
        data2.put("Germany", map);
```

Now.. My problem is how to put my objects into hashmap.

Here's my code in fetching the array object.

```
     while(rs.next()){
                     PropertyData reader = new PropertyData();
                     id = rs.getInt("id");
                     prop_name = rs.getString("prop_name");
                     prop_value = rs.getString("prop_value");
                     engine_name = rs.getString("engine_name");
                     //other setter..


                     reader.setId(id);
                     reader.setPropName(prop_name);
                     reader.setPropValue(prop_value);
                     reader.setEngineName(engine_name);
                     //other setter..

                     prop.add(reader);
                 }
```

From the code above. I want to put the **id** on hashmap key and **propname** on hashmap string name. Once selected, I want to display other values referencing the **id**.

And this is where my object has been added.

```
    static List<PropertyData> prop = new ArrayList<PropertyData>();
```

I tried to initialized it on my hashmap but it returned null.

Comment: It is impossible to know what you would like to do, ask better question, post some code that is complete (ready to run) and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It would be sufficient just to say *what* you want to put and *where* you want to put it. 2 lines of code.

Comment: okay wait ill edit it

Answer (score 0):

```
 new HashMap<String, String>()
```

says that key will be of type String and value will be of type String. If you want to have PropertyData in the value then define it as

```
  new HashMap<String, PropertyData>()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the HashMap with the below notation, you can add a list to your map..

```
HashMap<String, List<PropertyData>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have data in this list:

```
List<PropertyData> prop = new ArrayList<PropertyData>();
```

Now, create the map like this (if `PropertyData` has an unique `id` - also set size as the size of the array, resizing will be done only once):

```
HashMap<Integer, PropertyData> map = new HashMap<>(prop.size());
```

And this is how you place it in the map:

```
for (PropertyData pd : prop) map.put(pd.getId(), pd);
```

If `id` in `PropertyData` is not unique, create `int hashCode()` function that will create unique `int` (based on values in all variables - IDE can create that for you).

Comment: I tried this but the IDE suggests to add cast to map then it became like this. **((List<PropertyData>) map).add(pd.getId(), pd);** Then i got an error java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: sorry, my bad wrong function it should be map.put not map.add.. i will update my answer...

Comment: Hi bro I've got a follow up question if it's okay. I can get all the values in the sysout inside the loop but when I implented it I can only retrieve the last element of the array. Maybe I'm calling it wrong outside the loop? What is the proper way to call it or pass it outside the loop? thanks a lot

Comment: inside the `PropertyData` loop I have this code `countries  = new HashMap<Integer, PropertyData>();
   countries.put(pd.getId(),pd);` and I placed it here `private Map<Integer, PropertyData> countries;`  Now when I call it in my xhtml, my dropdown display the value of "36" and it is the last element of my `id`

Comment: countries = new HashMap<Integer, PropertyData>(); this should be before the loop. If this is in the loop, you will create new map in each iteration so you will have only the last element.

Comment: yeah that's it. maybe my brain is just tired already. lol thanks a lot!